# JDBC - How to get parameter name of a stored procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am making a generic class to invoke mssql store procedures.
I would like to return a map of the output which has like key the name of the output parameter, like a value an object, which has like value the value of the output parameter.

I am starting playing with ParameterMetaData, but I couldn't find a way to get output parameter names, but only pmd.getParameterType(i) and pmd.getParameterTypeName(i))

How can I do that? thank you!

Comment: [`DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureColumns()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getProcedureColumns(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))?

Answer (score 0):

to get the value of that output parameter you will need to create a parameter of that output parameter type and pass that parameter to your stored procedure at run time. something like this.

```
DECLARE @Var datatype;          --<-- parameter to store the value

EXECUTE dbo.Proc_name @param1 = @Var OUTPUT  --<-- Using OUTPUT key word

SELECT @Var     --<-- Return value stored in Parameter do as it pleases you
```

Comment: thank you, but there are no way of doing it just with java and without  creating scripts?

Comment: I dont know about Java but if you are calling this stored procedure from sql server you will need to these steps in order to execute that stored procedure, these are the sql server requirements how you will handle this in Java i am sorry dont know about that :)